# Cakephp 3 delete entry confirmation using bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to use a bootstrap modal to confirm delete operation. I am using Cakephp 3 and am new to it.

So far I am able to create this much.

If i can successfully replace  with the id of the button that was clicked, Then the issue will be solved

UsersController.php

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    $user= $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user with id: {0} has been deleted.', h($id)));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

index.ctp

```
<?= $this->Html->tag('i','',['class' => 'fa fa-times fa-fw icon-delete deleteUser', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#confirmModal' , 'id' => $user->user_id ]) ?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">Are you sure?</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(
                    $this->Html->tag('button','Delete',['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right']),
                    ['action' => 'delete', <id_here>],
                    ['escape' => false])
                ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

The generated markup for the delete button part in the modal is

```
<form action="/boot/users/delete/ABCD20090004" name="post_56e141b0297cc915184088" style="display:none;" method="post"><input name="_method" value="POST"></form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.post_56e141b0297cc915184088.submit(); event.returnValue = false; return false;">
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Delete</button>
</a>
```

Comment: how are you passing the id to the delete button?

Comment: @madalinivascu That is my problem. i need to figure out a way to do it. and if thats done, the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(
                    $this->Html->tag('button','Delete',['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right']),
                    ['action' => 'delete',array('id'=>$user->user_id)],
                    ['escape' => false])
                ?>
```

Note: you will need a modal for each element in your list(loop)

Comment: The rows are generated dynamically and so if i use the above method, no matter which delete button is clicked, the last row will be deleted

Comment: paste the generated modal in your question

Comment: I have added. This is the output for using your method

Comment: Yes your answer will work if i dynamically create modals for every row of data. But I don't want it that way

Comment: you will need some ajax for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Pass the user id of the record to be deleted on the delete button on the modal as opposed to the delete button you are clicking on to display the modal. Modify the index.ctp as follows

Do not pass the user id at this point

```
<?= $this->Html->tag('i','',['class' => 'fa fa-times fa-fw icon-delete deleteUser', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#confirmModal']) ?>
```

Pass the id on the delete button below

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">Are you sure?</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right']); ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Also, do not forget to initialize the modal

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```